# Download the produced audio by Speech SpeechSynthesizer C#

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, speech, speech-synthesis, speechsynthesizer

Here's the code:

```
SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
                synth.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male, VoiceAge.Senior);
                // Configure the audio output.   
                synth.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();

                // Speak a string.  
                synth.Speak("Hello World");
```

After it's done playing I want it to just automatically download the produced audio, is there any way I can do this?

Comment: You can't do it after it's finished playing. You have to change the output before it speaks. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.setoutputtowavefile?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Okay, I fixed it now